# What happened to the recent API contest?

Tags: support, discussion

I am curious to know the results of recent [stackoverflow contest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-public-beta/)

It has been removed from the api.stackoverflow page and no updates were seen. I believe that the deadline for the results announcements are over.

Let the people know what is happening please !!

Comment: [Last I heard was](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4025826#4025826) "6-8 weeks... :) (We're working on it. Honest.)"

Comment: @agent86 Ya you are right !! There must be something said or done about this !!

Comment: Yea guys... this contest had lots of great submissions than the 1st contest...

Comment: @Pratheepch, mainly I was trying to point out that they're working on it and are aware we are all eagerly waiting the results :)  We must have patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're judging*, winners should be getting emails next week with a blog post to follow.

It was removed from the API homepage because the linked blog post was about *entering* the contest, and entry was closed at that point.  A few people were confused about whether they could still enter, seemed best to remove it.

So, basically, stay tuned!

<sub>*Currently everything but the library winner has been sorted out.</sub>